# How to get a specific value instead of the printed name, of choices, in R Shiny select-Input

Tags: r, shiny, selectinput

I am building a Shiny app, where I have a **selectizeInput**.
The options to select are country Names, stored in a data.frame along their three-digit codes.

**Country**

| name | code |
| --- | --- |
| Aruba | ABW |
| Afghanistan | AFG |
| ... | ... |

In my shiny app, I call **selectizeInput**, in the UI-part like this:

```
selectizeInput(inputId = 'inSelect',
               label = "countries",
               choices = country$name,
               multiple = TRUE,
               options = list(maxItems = 4, 
               placeholder = 'select up to 4 countries'))
```

When selecting countries, I get a list of the names of them in the inSelect variable.

e.g. when I select *Afghanistan*, **inSelect** has the Value *Afghanistan*.

Is there a possibility, to get a different Value as the output.
So not the Name, but the code, stored next to it in the Table?

e.g. when I select *Afghanistan*, **InSelect** gets the Value *AFG*.

I know, that I can write the choice names down alongside their values. But **Country** is a table of ~200 rows.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here's a quick app that does what you want, in short you can define the countries as names for the vector `code`

```
library(shiny)
country <- c("Aruba","Afghanistan")
code <- c("ABW","AFG")
choices <- code
names(choices) <- country

ui <- fluidPage(
    selectInput(inputId = 'inSelect',
                label = "countries",
                choices = choices
                multiple = TRUE),
    textOutput("selected")
    
)

server <- function(input, output) {
    output$selected <- renderText({
        input$inSelect
    })
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

For your purposes, for data.frame `df` use:

```
choices <- df$code
names(choices) <- df$country
```

This way the association between the two is defined as a single vector on app load, and you don't need to look up the codes in the table over and over (this answer is faster).

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can get the corresponding value on the server side using `match`.

Here's a quick and small shiny app.

```
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage({
  fluidRow(column(6, selectizeInput(inputId = 'inSelect',
                 label = "countries",
                 choices = country$name,
                 multiple = TRUE)), 
           column(6, verbatimTextOutput('text')))
  
})

server <- function(input, output) {
  output$text <- renderPrint({
    req(input$inSelect)
    country$code[match(input$inSelect,country$name)]
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

[image]

**data**

```
country <- data.frame(name = c('Aruba', 'Afghanistan'), code = c('ABW', 'AFG'))
```

Comment: Thank you for the fast answer. 
I already thought about that, but it came into my mind, that it could be quite an expenditure, to search and match the value again. So I thought about a solution "inside" the selectizeInput. 
Also thanks again. I am only getting started with R, so I really had no Idea, how to implement that.